# Why does this Python cast behave differently for map and without map

Tags: python, string, dictionary, casting, int

Why do these two print statements produce different outcomes when the two casts from int to string appear to do the same thing ? What am I missing ?

board is a list of integers

```
#ex.1
print ' '.join(map(str, board[:3]))
#ex.2
print ' '.join(str(board[:3]))

#out.1
0 1 2
#out.2
[ 0 ,   1 ,   2 ]
```

Comment: What's `board`?

Comment: What "casts"? `map` and `str` do different things entirely. `map` builds a list that results from mapping the function onto an iterable.In this case, you get the list that results from applying `str` to every element in your original list.  `str` itself returns a string representation of your object. In this case, for a `list`, it is the string that you see when you would just do `print(board[:3])`

Comment: Please provide a [mcve].

Comment: I was trying to remove the [] and , from the print  and was just wondering why the 1st example map removed them even though it was creating a list too but the second did not.

Comment: Because in the second example, you *aren't creating a list, you are creating a string*. `map(...)` returns a *list*, and `str(...)` returns a *string*.

Comment: right but if thats the case there I would not have thought there would be be [] or ,

Comment: Why? What do you usually see when you `print a_list`? Doesn't it have brackets and commas?

Answer (score 3):

```
print(" ".join(map(str, board[:3])))
```

maps each item of the sliced `board` to a literal integer and joins it with spaces (probably what you want, and the right thing to do)

```
print(' '.join(str(board[:3])))
```

converts the `list` as its *representation* (with brackets and all) and then inserts a space between each character. Not what you want.

Answer (score 1):

Clearly look on what exactly happen in your code:

First case:

```
In [4]: map(str,boards[:3])
Out[4]: ['0', '1', '2']

In [5]: ''.join(map(str,boards[:3]))
Out[5]: '012'
```

Convert to all elements in the list to string format and when you use `join` it will joins those elements.

Second case:

```
In [6]: str(boards[:3])
Out[6]: '[0, 1, 2]'

In [7]: ''.join(str(boards[:3]))
Out[7]: '[0, 1, 2]'
```

First entire list convert as list and while using join on a string it will give the same.

Comment: so its the .join that appears to be responsible for removing the brackets and , from a list right.

Comment: Actually `join` do like list of strings converts to a string with specific character which we defined over there. In jean case he used space and  my used empty string.